# How to keep track of keys javascript html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make it so that if a user on the html page presses the letters A, H, then A, an alert box comes up saying "Aha, you've found the secret!"

How do I accomplish this with Jquery, Javascript, etc?

Comment: Try it! If your attempt doesn't work out, you'll have enough code and explanation for a good question.

Comment: The issue is I know how to handle one keypress event, but the difficulty is keeping track of the sequence of multiple key presses is what I dont know how to handle. Note the sequence has to be 'A', then 'B', then 'A'. If the user had entered any other key in 'R' in between, it wouldnt trigger the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more efficient ways to do this, but I figured this is the best way to demonstrate to you the core principles at work. This is using key down event handlers, and the jQuery framework.

```
var step1 = false;
var step2 = false;

$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (step2) {
    // Step 2 - Represents we've cleared both A (1) and H
        if (event.keyCode == '65') {
            // We've found the last A!
            step2 = false;
            step1 = false;
            alert("Aha! You've found the secret!");
        } else {
            // It was a key other than A :( Reset to start
            step2 = false;
        }
    } else if (!step1) {
        // Step 1 - Represents we haven't started our chain yet
        if (event.keyCode == '65') {
            // Someone pressed A! Step 1 is DONE!
            step1 = true;
        }
    } else {
        // Step 1 is done, but we're waiting on Step 2... Will it be?
        if (event.keyCode == '72') {
            // H has been pressed! We're cleared through Step 2
            step2 = true;
            step1 = false;
        } else {
            // H wasn't press :(, Let's go back to the start
            step1 = false;
        }
    }
});
```

**Addendum** : It's worth noting that the integer 65 represents a keyboard press of the letter `a` and 72 a keyboard press of the letter `h`

Comment: This is some hard to follow code. There are far more straightforward ways to do this.

Comment: @mrtsherman I disagree, I find if-else statements easy to trace through. Moreover the code you provided doesn't help the OP accomplish his or her task. You're simply demonstrating a keypress event.

Comment: Yeah I know. I said that in my answer.

Comment: I think you will find this far more readable. Six lines shorter, requires one global instead of two, extendable to longer than three letter words and for me far more readable than a bunch of nested if statements. http://jsfiddle.net/PTyYL/3/

Comment: By your own logic, if someone is such a programming novice that they can barely trace through if-else statements then I think the introduction of a switch statement will only serve to confuse further. As I plainly stated at the beginning of my answer, there **are** other more efficient ways to do this. Personally I'd use a method similar to the one you provided; but my game here is to be instructional. Thankfully the OP has many different ways to learn from, and I would appreciate it if you would not be so aggressive against the opinions of others.

Comment: `keydown` tells you nothing about the characters typed. Use `keypress` instead.

Comment: ahaha the steps are out of order why would you do that... :(

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to handle the "document.onkeypress" event.

Comment: That keeps track of one key, but I need to keep track of the sequence of multiple keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
var secretCode = 'AHA',
    codeIndex = 0;

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.which === secretCode.charCodeAt(codeIndex)) {
        codeIndex++;
    } else {
        codeIndex = 0;
    }
    if (codeIndex === secretCode.length) {
        codeIndex = 0;
        alert("Aha, you've found the secret!");
    }
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rr2s7/1/)

Comment: Aha, almost exactly same with my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var sequence = "DDE";
var i = 0;

document.onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var keycode = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
    if(keycode == sequence.charCodeAt(i)){
        if(i == sequence.length -1 ){
            alert("You've found the secret");
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using the correct event, which is `keypress`. `keydown` and `keyup` are for detecting physical keys (which will vary between keyboard types) while `keypress` is for detecting typed characters, regardless of keyboard layout. The following does case insensitive matching, but you could trivially alter it to be case sensitive.

```
var secret = "aha", correctCharCount = 0;

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var lowerChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode).toLowerCase();
    if (lowerChar == secret.charAt(correctCharCount)) {
        correctCharCount++;
        if (correctCharCount == secret.length) {
            alert("Aha, you've found the secret!");
            correctCharCount = 0;
        }
    } else {
        // Check whether the character typed is the first character
        // in the secret
        correctCharCount = (lowerChar == secret.charAt(0)) ? 1 : 0;
    }
};
```